# Remove empty cells from standard ASP.NET table

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, cell

I am trying to make a timetable using a .txt file as a source, but I am having some trouble. I am creating a website, using C# and ASP.NET.

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

I tried so hard to put all the data in the same 5 rows, but it's just seems impossible, they always hop to the different rows. Just to make things clear, this is my expectation:

[image]

Just in case, this is the code I wrote, maybe I messed up somewhere:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("App_Data/Classes.txt"))

foreach(string line in allLines){
string[] parts = line.Split(',');

TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell number = new TableCell();
TableCell lesson = new TableCell();
TableCell number2 = new TableCell();
TableCell lesson2 = new TableCell();
TableCell number3 = new TableCell();
TableCell lesson3 = new TableCell();
TableCell number4 = new TableCell();
TableCell lesson4 = new TableCell();
TableCell number5 = new TableCell();
TableCell lesson5 = new TableCell();

if (parts[1] == "Monday" & parts[0] == "5a klase")
{
    number.Text = parts[2];
    lesson.Text = parts[3];
}

if (parts[1] == "Tuesday" & parts[0] == "5a klase")
{
    number2.Text = parts[2];
    lesson2.Text = parts[3];
}

if (parts[1] == "Wednesday" & parts[0] == "5a klase")
{
    number3.Text = parts[2];
    lesson3.Text = parts[3];
}

if (parts[1] == "Thursday" & parts[0] == "5a klase")
{
    number4.Text = parts[2];
    lesson4.Text = parts[3];
}

if (parts[1] == "Friday" & parts[0] == "5a klase")
{
    number5.Text = parts[2];
    lesson5.Text = parts[3];
}

row.Cells.Add(number);
row.Cells.Add(lesson);
row.Cells.Add(number2);
row.Cells.Add(lesson2);
row.Cells.Add(number3);
row.Cells.Add(lesson3);
row.Cells.Add(number4);
row.Cells.Add(lesson4);
row.Cells.Add(number5);
row.Cells.Add(lesson5);

Table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

}
Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. Here's how the .txt file looks like (ignore the non-English names, those are school subjects in Lithuanian):

[image]

Comment: You are creating a new row using : TableRow row = new TableRow();  You should only execute this line the first time through the loop.

Comment: @jdweng I entered TableRow row = new TableRow(); before the loop, now it puts everything into one row.

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the source txt file?

Comment: @Jonathan there is a loop before the code I specified. Let me edit the post.

Comment: @VDWWD sure, one moment

Comment: If you look at all of those if statements, your code is only going to go into one of them for each line. You want it to be going into all of them to build all of the cells. There's no way, for example, that for a given row element 1 can be both Monday and Tuesday

Comment: @Jonathan and just how might I do that? The problem is, whenever I use "if", the stuff inside "if" separates to other rows... And those "if"s are important

Comment: @Jonathan any suggestions then? I'm pretty desperate

Comment: It's because you need more than 1 row of your import for 1 row in the table. But you're processing one row of import at a time

Comment: @Jonathan, oh, believe me, I tried putting them into separate rows. Somehow, magically, same happens. I have absolutely no idea how

Comment: I like this problem  this is what I would do: create a poco for the structure (int ordinal; string day; etc). Then deserialize your text file into a list of the object. From there, instead of looping through the items, you could query them. Items.FirstOrDefault(I=>i.ordinal == currentLoop && i.day == "Tuesday") etc

Comment: This has the benefit that you can validate your data when you import it, you can have variable number of entries per day, etc

Answer (score 0):

So here's something to start from. I just freehanded it, so I'm sure there's syntax and other errors in there, but try it, change your own code, etc

```
public class DoWork(){

  var scheduleEntries = new List<ScheduleEntry>();
        File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("App_Data/Classes.txt")).Select(i=>scheduleEntries.Add(new ScheduleEntry(i)));

  var maxRowCount = scheduleEntries.Max(i=>i.Ordinal);

  for (int k = 1; k <= maxRowCount; k++){
    var tableRow = new TableRow;
    // Monday
     var mondayCellItem = scheduleEntries.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Ordinal == k && i.Day == "Monday")
    var mondayCell = new TableCell{
      Text = $"{mondayCellItem.Class}"

    // Tuesday, etc

    tableRow.Cells.Add(mondayCell);
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tuesdayCell);
    //etc
    }

  }

  internal class ScheduleEntry(){
    public string Day {get;set;}
    public int Ordinal {get;set;}
    public string ClassName {get;set;}

    public ScheduleEntry(string inRow){
      var values = inRow.Split(',');
      Day = values[1]; // should do some validation here
      Ordinal = int.Parse(values[2]); // and here
      ClassName = values[3]; // and here
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to split the text file into rows which are already split by the comma. Then it's just a matter of looping all the items. It all works dynamically so you can add as much weekdays and rows per weekday as needed.

```
//create a list with the rows already split by comma
List<string[]> allRows = File.ReadLines(Server.MapPath("/textfile1.txt")).Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToList();

//group by weekday
var sortedList = allRows.GroupBy(x => x[1]).ToList();

//get the max number of rows needed
var rowCount = sortedList.Max(x => x.Count()) + 1;

//create a new table
Table table = new Table();

//fill the table with rows and columns
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow();

    for (int j = 0; j < (sortedList.Count * 2); j++)
    {
        //if it is the first row add the row headers
        if (i == 0)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

            if (j % 2 == 1)
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = sortedList[j /2].Key });
            else
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = "Nr" });
         }
         else
         {
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        }
    }

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

//loop all the weekdays
for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count; i++)
{
    int j = 1;

    //loop all the items within a weekday
    foreach (var item in sortedList[i])
    {
        //the item[x] is based on the sample txt file, it is the row split by comma index
        table.Rows[j].Cells[i * 2].Text = item[2];
        table.Rows[j].Cells[(i * 2) + 1].Text = item[3];
        j++;
    }
}
```